# How to create VB .NET Project on Visual studio Mac?

Tags: .net, vb.net, macos

All

I want create VB .net web project using visual studio mac book version. How it's create. There were only the empty vb project can be created using by VS Mac. So how to configured it's as web project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS for Mac only supports ASP.NET Core for web development and VB is not supported by ASP.NET Core even on Windows at present.  You'll need to use C# for now at least and possibly always.

Comment: It doesn't matter what your manager wants if the product doesn't support it. If they want to use VS to create a VB web app then they have to do it on Windows.  It's that simple.  Putting some VBScript in a web page is nothing to do with VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks for helped